# move_uploaded_file not working..File in moved to wrong directory

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to resize an image and save the path to my database and I also want to move it to a map. Everything works fine except for the move to the directory. I also know I need to use MySQL or PDO instead of MySQL but this is just an example.
Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
//Database connection made

error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";
define("MAX_SIZE","400");
function getExtension($str) {

     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
}
$errors=0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $image=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadedfile=$_FILES['file'];

    if ($image)
    {
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension= getExtension($filename);
        $extension =strtolower($extension);
        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png")    && ($extension !="gif"))
        {
            echo 'Onbekende image extensie';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if ($size > MAX_SIZE*9999999999)
            {
                echo "Je hebt het size limit overschreden";
                $errors=1;
            }
            if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg")
            {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            }
            else if ($extension=="png")
            {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }
            else 
            {
                $src=imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }
            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

            $newwidth=240;
            $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
            imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            imagedestroy($src);
            imagedestroy($tmp);
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($filename,$folder.$filename);
    $handle = $folder.$filename;
}

//database connection closed + file pad saved to database
```

The file is being uploaded in the map above the 'upload' map.
Now the file is saved in 'root/' but it should be 'root/uploads/'.

Can someone solve my `move_uploaded_file` problem?

Comment: Why do you use that much code, when you can do it more simple?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$folder="uploads/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$folder);
```

Comment: yes it works but now he saves my image in both directories (in uploads and root) how i fix that?

Comment: is there a way to fix it

Comment: you have imagejpeg in your code this will also create a image so you have two images created in two different directories

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on your move_uploaded_file arrangement, don't forget to place the all param in order, first string should be $from and follow by $to.
You can also go through this link for more details Click [here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)!
This works with [reference links][blog] as well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).